# Non-breaking spaces inside dashes

Tags: punctuation, french

Exists a method or environment to write in French, exactly like a quote in « guillemets », a text in — en dashes — with automatic non-breaking spaces inside ? So, I used this trivial method, but it cut between dash & exemple inside at line break : 
`beginning —~exemple~— end.`

I'm using `[frenchb]{scrbook}`, `[frenchb]{babel}` & `[babel,french=guillemets*]{csquotes}` packages, with xelatex & encoding = UTF-8 Unicode. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define `\dashquote` which works in pairs. First (and each odd) occurrence of the `\dashquote` works like `--~` and second (and each even) occurrence of the `\dashqoute` works like `~--`. And finally, you can set (in XeTeX) the unicoded character `—` as an active character and define it as `\dashquote`.

```
\def\dashquote{\bgroup\def\dashquote{\unskip~--\egroup}--~\ignorespaces}
\catcode`—=13 \def—{\dashquote} % the Unicode character — is defined here

Text — quoted example — text. % Works like: Text --~quoted example~-- text.

Text —quoted example— text. % Works the same, like: Text --~quoted example~-- text.
```

Comment: It should be `\protected\def–{\dashquote}`. Forgetting a closing emdash inside a LaTeX environment will lead to a weird error message.

Answer (score 5):

Use the UTF-8 character U+2014 (EM DASH) or `\textemdash`:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[babel,french=guillemets*]{csquotes}

\begin{document}

\parbox{0pt}{beginning ---~exemple~--- end}

\bigskip

\parbox{0pt}{beginning \textemdash~exemple~\textemdash{} end}

\bigskip

\parbox{0pt}{beginning —~exemple~— end}

\end{document}
```

In the example the `\parbox` is just to force LaTeX to break as much as possible. The third `\parbox` contains the `—` character that is equivalent to typing `\textemdash`.

The problem with `---` is that TeX adds an empty discretionary after a hyphen `-` or any ligature that ends with it.

[image]

For XeLaTeX there's a workaround (for mysterious reasons, XeTeX adds the empty discretionary after the emdash):

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[babel,french=guillemets*]{csquotes}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{—}{\mbox{—}}

\begin{document}

\parbox{0pt}{beginning ---~exemple~--- end}

\bigskip

\parbox{0pt}{beginning —~exemple~— end}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if there's a better system. This one only works between two em-dashes, though. **EDIT:** I didn't see that you used XeLaTeX

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\newunicodechar{—}{\delimitedbyemdash}
\def\delimitedbyemdash#1—{\textemdash~\csname tl_trim_spaces:n\endcsname{#1}~\textemdash}

\begin{document}

Is this —what you mean— in the question?

\end{document}
```